# Leer archivo BLOB de la bbdd

Tags: php, mysql

La cuestión es que he insertado un archivo de tipo BLOB en un campo de mi tabla, dentro de una bbdd en local.

Para leer el archivo, utilizando PDO, he creado un archivo que crea la conexión con mi base de datos y otro archivo que se encarga de leer el BLOB, requiriendo obviamente del archivo de conexión.

Cuando lo ejecuto, en pantalla, aparece el ID y el tipo del registro de la tabla donde se encuentra el BLOB, pero no se muestra el contenido (en este caso, una foto en formato png), más especificamente aparece el pequeño icono de la imagen 'rota'.

- Éste es el archivo de conexión:

  ```
  <?php

  try{

  $base= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');

  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //$base->exec('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8');

  }catch(Exception $e){
     die ('Error' . $e->getMessage());
     echo "Línea del error: " . $e->getLine();
  }

  return $base;

  ?>
  ```

Y este mi código de lectura:

```
<?php

echo "<br>";

$Id="";
$contenido="";
$tipo="";

require("Conexion.php");

$sql="SELECT * FROM ARCHIVOS WHERE Id=12";

$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

$resultado->execute();

while($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $Id=$fila["Id"];
    $contenido=$fila["Contenido"];
    $tipo=$fila["Tipo"];
}

?>

<center>

    <h1>Leer archivo BLOB de la BBDD</h1>

    <br>

    <?php

        echo "Id: " . $Id . "<br>";
        echo "Tipo: " . $tipo . "<br>";
        echo "Contenido: " . "<img src='data:image/png; base64," . base64_encode($contenido) . "' '/>";

    ?>

 </center>
```

Answer (score 1):

trata convirtiento el dato BLOB a texto de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql="SELECT convert(Contenido USING utf8) as png, ARCHIVOS.* FROM ARCHIVOS WHERE Id=12";

$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

$resultado->execute();

while($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $Id=$fila["Id"];
    $contenido=$fila["png"];
    $tipo=$fila["Tipo"];
}
```

me cuentas si te sirvio.
saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Sé qué tú pregunta es para **MySQL**, agregaré está respuesta qué a mi me sirvió en su momento, pero en **SQL**, es probable que te pueda servir de referencia.

Puedes crear una función para tenerla disponible siempre que la requieras.

> EN SQL

```
USE [pruebas]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[imagenABase64]
(
    @bin varbinary(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result varchar(max)

    SELECT @result = (select cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@bin")))', 'varchar(max)'));

    RETURN @result
END
```

Después con la función ya creada, realizas la consulta:

```
SELECT pruebas.DBO.imagenABase64(Contenido) AS IMG
FROM pruebas.ARCHIVOS
WHERE Id = 12
```